# Exposing a type of field operation (flag lists) for search index view

Tags: 7, flags, views

I installed the flag list operations module which gives me the ability to do **operations** on my views results. But this **flag list operations** doesn't show up on my **search index view** as seen below.

I'm sure there is some parameter or variable that is set in the **flag list** module that is preventing this **operation** to show up on the **search index view**.

What should I be looking for in the **flag list** module code to enable this operation to show up in the search index view?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those flag list operations come from a Views handler; they're applied only to the node entity type in `flag_lists_views_data_alter`.

The *Indexed node* isn't a node entity, it's something specific to the search API module (added in `search_api_views_views_data`). It only contains fields that are indexed, plus any extra stuff search API or contrib modules add on.

I haven't tried it, but you may be able to include the `nid` in the index, and add a relationship in the View to *Content*. That would, in theory, give you access to everything that Views knows about for a node.

Failing that, you'll probably have to implement your own Views handler, implement `hook_views_data_alter`, and find the table whose field handler you need to override (it'll be `search_api_index_MACHINE_NAME`). The class in `includes/flag_lists_handler_field_ops.inc` would probably be a good template to start from.

Comment: thanks clive, im totally stuck for the past 2 days. see: http://prntscr.com/i5nmoi  i added a new array to the existing $data array and pointed it to a new handler --- but it still doesn't show up on the "search index" view. I tried to look at the views_bulk_operations.views.inc and see how they did it as that "operation" shows up on the search index view. I'm totally lost on where you find this "table" you speak of. The **extended class** that is used in flag_lists is views_handler_field but views_bulk_operations uses the class **views_handler_field_entity** ...

Answer (score 0):

Took me a good 20-30+ hours to figure this one out as this involved knowing how Views Handlers work and reverse engineering the flag list module code.

In the case of the flag_list module not working with the search api index, it had to do with creating a new handler. The flag list operations handler was extending the class **views_handler_field** but you needed **views_handler_field_entity** for the search api view to see it. I'm not sure why, but I followed the views_bulk_operations module as an example.

From there I copied all the code from the **original** flag list operations handler code into my new handler that uses the views_handler_field_entity with some modifications in the code that had to do with targeting the **nid** as the **$data** array was different from the **$data** array in the **views_handler_field**.

Then, to get the flag list operations **form** to show up, I had to find the form_alter in the flag_lists.module file and have it recognize the new handler I had.

In total I had to modify:

- flag_lists.module
- flag_lists.views.module
- flag_lists_handler_field_ops_xxx.inc (this is my new handler file called xxx)

[image]